# What's the meaning of the org-mode agenda footer?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Can anyone explain what the first characters of the footer mean and what is the date in parenthesis?

[image: my org-mode footer]

How is this part of emacs really called? I'd be happy to look this up myself but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

That line is called [the mode line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mode-Line.html), and acts as a status bar in Emacs.

The first characters indicate the buffer's coding system, input method, read-only and modified status.